# M2 - How to fix wrong customer import

Tags: customer, import, customer-account, address

I have a live webshop and imported user from the old webshop. The amount of accounts is around 6500. The was something wrong with the import so everyone has a wrong address in their account. So I made a new import with the correct addresses, but now all the accounts has multiple addresses, the wrong address and the correct address.

Is there a way to remove the wrong addresses from the accounts?

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed, I removed all the addresses from customer_address_entity with the create date from the first import.